# Why does `const arg = arg;` produce a "Cannot access before initialization" error?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, arguments, constants

I found really weird behavior that I never thought about before. I'm not sure if this is related to TDZ because I thought TDZ was about from outer scope to inner scope, not the other way around like this case. Pay attention to `arg` in below examples.

```
// Works

const test = {
   func: (arg) => {
      const obj = {
         foo: arg,
      }
      return obj.foo;
   }
}
```

```
// Error

const test = arg => {
   {
      const arg = arg; // Cannot access 'arg' before initialization
   }
}
```

Comment: Confusing error messages aside, why try and redeclare the function argument?

Comment: @Phil Why not? Maybe I want to make it constant.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking _why_ this is an error? I'm just trying to head off a bunch of answers showing you how to avoid the error without addressing the _real_ question

Comment: @Phil already taken care of.

Comment: @Inigo yep, excellent update

Comment: I updated the question so that when it appears in search results, people will know right away whether it's relevant to why *they* are getting that error (most likely not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that `let` and `const` declarations are both [block-scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), which means **that they are only accessible within the `{ }` surrounding them**. So because of `const` or `let` the `variable (arg)` from the outer scope won't be accessed if another `variable (arg)` inside a block scope gets defined.

Or in other words: The variable `arg` inside a `parentheses` or `curly brackets` is not the same as the `arg` you pass to the function because you make use of `let` or `const` inside.

While parsing the block scope the engine already reserves the name for EVERY variable defined inside. But they will only be accessible **after** the declaration and evaluation using const or let.

So reading it, while writing to it, causes the error you see.

```js
var variable;
{ // [block/env start] 
   let variable = variable; // ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variable' before initialization
} // [block/env end]
```

What happens during `let variable = variable` is that it has to read the right hand side before it assigns the value/reference to the left hand side, but per definition the variable is not available before declaration, therefor it throws the error.

Another example would be:

```js
var variable;
{
  console.log(variable); // ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variable' before initialization
  let variable;
}
```

The execution order is similar to the assignment in your example and throws the same error. It won't access the outer `variable` because another `variable` gets defined inside that block scope using let/const.

You can also take a look of the [Let and Const Declarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-declarations-and-the-variable-statement).

> let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment. **The variables are created when their containing Environment Record is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable's LexicalBinding is evaluated.** A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer's AssignmentExpression when the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created. If a LexicalBinding in a let declaration does not have an Initializer the variable is assigned the value undefined when the LexicalBinding is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've declared a *new* `arg` variable inside the function block, and that *hides* the `arg` variable in the outer scope, e.g. the one declared as a function parameter.

Thus the `arg` on the right hand side of the `const arg = arg;` assignment references the same variable as the one referenced on the left hand side. It is *NOT* referencing the arrow function `arg` parameter. Thus you are doing exactly as the error says, referencing a variable before you initialized it (while trying to initialize it!).

This is easily demonstrated by using unique names:

```
const test = arg => {
   {
      const inner_arg = arg;
   }
}
```

Why would you use the same name anyway? Not only does it result in the above problem, it is impossible to read code. Perhaps you are doing this out of habit like you would in a class constructor? But in that case you can differentiate between the parameter and the class field with `this`, e.g. `this.arg = arg`.